# How to get Django to use an updated python on Mac OS X server?

Tags: django, python-2.7, osx-server

I am using Django on my Mac OS X server. Things are fine, so far. I have been using python 2.6.1 and all works well. I upgraded Python to version 2.7.3. Invoking python in the terminal brings up version 2.7.3, as expected. Checking Django using the {% debug %) reveals that Django is still using the original python 2.6.1 interpreter.

On this system, /usr/local/bin contains a symlink to ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

In /usr/bin I find the python interpreter, and from that directory, invoking ./python gets python 2.6.1 running.

My $PATH is 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin

which I believe must have been altered on the python 2.7.3 install.

What is considered the optimal way to get the command line and Django using the same Python? I am considering either moving the framework version to /usr/bin and sitting a symlink in the framework to the moved new version. On the system is also a /Library/Python directory, that contains the site-packages for versions 2.3, 2.5, and 2.6.  In /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages are the major goodies django, mercurial, and south.

Where are people putting things, nowadays? I mean, I know I could move things around, but I would like to anticipate where the Django project is going so future upgrades can go smoothly.

Comment: You can avoid this by using Homebrew to install python -> `brew install python`

Answer (score 1):

Install it against the updated Python.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I reinstall django then it would seem that I will need to reinstall all other packages, like south, and mercurial as well as django. Isn't there a recommended structure for where the various packages and utilities are supposed to go?

Comment: You'd still need to recompile all the bytecode for the new VM.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting your app within a `virtualenv` container and specifying the version of Python when you create it - as per: [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)